# Python Flask Login Current_User Not Always Available

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

any ideas on the following?

This is my User Class:

```
class UserType(db.Document):
firstName = db.StringField()
lastName = db.StringField()
email = db.StringField()
passwordHash = db.StringField()
created = db.DateTimeField()
lastEdit = db.DateTimeField()
lastSignIn = db.DateTimeField()
hostOrTest = db.StringField()

def to_json(self):
    return jsonify({
        '_id': str(self.pk),
        'First Name': self.firstName,
        'Last Name': self.lastName,
        'Email': self.email,
        'Creation Date': self.created,
        'Edit Date': self.lastEdit,
        'Last Sign In': self.lastSignIn,
        'hostOrTest': self.hostOrTest
    })

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

def is_active(self):
    return True

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

def get_id(self):
    return str(self.pk)

@property
def host(self):
    if self.hostOrTest == "host":
        return True
    else:
        return False

@property
def test(self):
    if self.hostOrTest == 'test':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and this is my login endpoint:

```
@app.route("/api/Login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
request_data = request.get_json()
email = request_data["email"]
if 'passwordHash' in request_data:
    passwordHash = request_data["passwordHash"]
else:
    passwordHash = request_data["email"]
userObj = UserType.objects(email=email, passwordHash=passwordHash).first()
if userObj:
    login_user(userObj, remember=True, fresh=False)
    userObj.update(lastSignIn=datetime.datetime.now())
    return(jsonify('success'), 200)
else:
    return(jsonify("Username or password error"), 401)
```

This is all works as expected and when I question the server to see if the user is logged in with the endpoint:

```
@app.route("/api/isUserLoggedIn", methods=["GET"])
def apiIsUserLoggedIn():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    print(f"User ID is {current_user.get_id()}")
    return('True')
elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
    return('False')
```

It works as expected and printed to the console is the Users ID.

However when I run this function:

```
@app.route('/socketIO/API/createRoom', methods=["POST"])
@socketio.event
#@login_required
def createRoom():
quizId = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                 for i in range(6))

questions = []
timeLimit = 5
quizStarted = 'False'
print(f"User ID is {current_user.get_id()}")
activeRooms = ActiveRooms(
    roomId=quizId,
    connectedUserId=[current_user.get_id()],
    allConnectedUsers=[current_user.get_id()],
    dateTime=datetime.datetime.now(),
    questions=questions,
    timeLimit=timeLimit,
    quizStarted=quizStarted,
    currentQuestion="null"
)
activeRooms.save()
print(f'room created with quiz ID: {quizId}')
# CHANGEBACK emit(f'ID {quizId}')

return(f'ID {quizId}')
```

these are all apart of the same file as well, in the createRoom function I get User ID is None printed everytime, even though in my IsUserLoggedIn function it works fine.

Any ideas?

PS This is my first post on StackOverflow so I hope I didn't mess anything up! :)

Thanks!

Comment: When is the Socket.IO connection made? Before or after the user logs in?

Comment: The socketIO connection is made before the user logins. Does this affect things?

Comment: Yes. The way the session works is explained in the [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementation_notes.html#access-to-flask-s-context-globals). I have also written an [article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-socketio-and-the-user-session) on my blog about different options you have to manage your session with Flask-SocketIO.

Comment: Hi, yes I have read your article and the docs but I can't seem to find a way to make my login Endpoint register current-user data to the same session as the socket io connection. If I had users login using http and then initiated the socket connection would this connection join the same session automatically? (socketio is NOT handling sessions)

Comment: What you are trying to do is exactly the one use case that cannot be supported. You have two options. 1) switch to server-side sessions (maybe with Flask-Session) and set manage_session=False. 2) Delay the Socket.IO connection until after your session cookie is updated with your user's logged in state.

Comment: ahhh okay thank you for your response, this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `self.pk`, but I don't see this defined anywhere. Is this supposed to get the primary key? Because then you might want to set `primary_key=True` for an attribute (e.g. `email = db.StringField(primary_key=True)`)

Comment: Hi, self.pk is just to return the auto assigned ID in the mongo database

Comment: Are you sure this is defined? Can you try printing get_id() for some user?

Comment: yes this is definitely working as in the "/api/isUserLoggedIn" endpoint it works as expected

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea then. The only odd thing I can note is that the function is both a route and a socketio event. Usually these are seperate functions, see this example: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/main/example/app.py

Comment: okay thank you it is very possible that you may be correct as I have other just HTTP endpoints and they seem to work. Thank you very much!